# react js how to import only the required function from a file and not the all functions

Tags: javascript, reactjs

### this is my functions.js file

```
export const f1 =()=>
{
console.log('palashf1');
}
export const f2 =()=>
{
console.log('palashf2');
}
```

---

and this is the main js file for react application

```
import {f1} from './functions';
```

// using f1 somewhere

---

when I go to console on my webpage and click the bundles I can see that f2 is also getting downloaded

Is there any version of import method that allows us to download only the js function we need and not all the functions of the file from where we are importing ?

creating a separate file for the function is the only solution ??

Comment: If you want to load certain pieces of code on demand instead of all at once, look into Code Splitting. If you want to leave unimported functions out of the bundle altogether, look into Tree Shaking. Both of these things are supported out of the box in Webpack 2 (although they do tend to be a little tricky to set up).

Comment: It's called tree shacking, or dead code elimination

Comment: @JoeClay thanks.. so I suppose that would serve my problem and I will be able to do that. Then great. Here I go for splitting and tree shaking.

Comment: @OmriLuzon Got it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Please upgrade [Webpack](https://webpack.js.org) to version 2 or newer as it supports [tree-shaking](https://webpack.js.org/guides/tree-shaking/) which eliminates unused exports.

As Webpack 2 supports native ES6 modules you must disable `babel` from transpiling ES6 modules to common-js format by configuring `babel-loader` presets (set `modules: false` in the `es2015` preset):

```
{
  test: /\.js$/,
  exclude: /node_modules/,
  loader: 'babel-loader',
  options: {
    presets: [
      [
        'es2015', {
          modules: false
        }
      ]
      ...
    ]
  }
}
```

Tree-shaking should work with this configuration, inspect with the console or [Webpack Bundle Analyzer Plugin](https://github.com/th0r/webpack-bundle-analyzer).